# PyLab contourf with experimental data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand and adapt the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x,y):
    return (1 - x / 2 + x**5 + y**3) * np.exp(-x**2 -y**2)

n = 256
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, n)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

pl.axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95])

pl.contourf(X, Y, f(X, Y), 8, alpha=.75, cmap=pl.cm.hot)
C = pl.contour(X, Y, f(X, Y), 8, colors='black', linewidth=.5)
pl.clabel(C, inline=1, fontsize=10)

pl.xticks(())
pl.yticks(())
pl.show()
```

Here we have a set of points `(x,y)` and a value for each point, computed with `f(x,y)`

Now, I have a set of computational results in the form of `x;y;output` in a txt output file that I read with `csv` module for example. The point is that I'm not understanding the data types here, probably the meshgrid. Let's say that each point is a key  `key` in a dictionary `FH_DICT` so as `FH_DICT[key]` will play the role of `f(x,y)` in the code above. But I don't know how to implement it, as the output value for each point it is not easy to express as a mathematical function.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need interpolate you points by a grid. For example `griddata`, `Rbf`, ... : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation

Comment: @HYRY could you please elaborate a little further? Thanks :)

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more on your x, y data. If (x, y) are not 2d arrays forming a rectangular grid you should probably use plt.tricontour instead of plt.contour. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html

Comment: @Gby Thanks I will read about your link. I actually solved it, I will post the code and the output at home.